# Using Xpath to add a new value to attributes

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to use xpath to navigate to the analysis/analysis parameter attributes by add in a new value:

As a first step I have tried retrieving a value from the analysis tag but cannot get this to work (no sample value being retrieved, no output in console). Can anyone see where I am going wrong here and then further show how I can then add a new value.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XPathTestReports {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {


                 String xpath = "/UserDocument/report-plan-catalog/collection/collection/collection/report-config/report-plan/settings[@analysis]";

                 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/workspace/savedreportscatalog.xml"));

                 DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                 DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                 Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

                 XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                 XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(xpath);
                 String attributeValue = "" + xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.STRING);
                 System.out.println(attributeValue);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       



    }
 }
```

XML Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<UserDocument>
  <report-plan-catalog>
    <collection timestamp="" title="report plans" uid="">
      <collection container-id="" timestamp="2015-04-29" title="*" uid="">
        <collection container-id="94533" timestamp="2015-04-29" title="*" uid="5cfc">
          <report-config container-id="5cfc" timestamp="2015-04-29" title="Asset" type="Risk" uid="4718">
            <configuration>
              <reportType>Live</reportType>
            </configuration>
            <report-plan name="Asset">
              <columns>
                <column name="Nom" subtotal-function="Sum" total-function="Sum"/>
                <column name="Id"/>
                <column name="Ref"/>
              </columns>
              <settings analysis="someValue" analysisParameters="" filtering-enabled="true" object-actions="false" show-object-actions="true" sorting-enabled="true"/>
              <viewpoint kind="simple">
                <slices/>
         </report-plan>
      </report-config>
    </collection>
  </collection>
</collection>
</report-plan-catalog>
</UserDocument>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still not very clear what your end goal is, but

```
/UserDocument/report-plan-catalog/collection/collection/collection/report-config/report-plan/settings[@analysis]
```

selects a `settings` element, given that is has an attribute `@analysis`, that's what the *predicate* (inside angle brackets) means. If that is not what you want, use

```
/UserDocument/report-plan-catalog/collection/collection/collection/report-config/report-plan/settings/@analysis
```

to select the `@analysis` attribute of the `settings` element.

---

Not very familiar with Java, but I'll make two further guesses:

- is there perhaps a *namespace* in your input document that you have not shown?
- perhaps this is not the right way to deal with *attribute nodes*. Try

  `string(/UserDocument/report-plan-catalog/collection/collection/collection/report-config/report-plan/settings/@analysis)`

---

**EDIT**: Now tested the Java code, and

```
String xpath = "/UserDocument/report-plan-catalog/collection/collection/collection/report-config/report-plan/settings/@analysis";
```

definitely works, after correcting the **input XML**, which is currently not well-formed - the `viewpoint` element is not closed.

I get as output:

```
$ java XPathTestReports
someValue
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I want to select @analysis attribute of the setting element. I have changed this to match your example but it still does not print anything in the system.out? My end goal is to pass in values from probably a HashMap but at the moment I am testing on an isolated xml file to see if I can pass in any kind of value to get that working first.

Comment: What would you expect `""` to print out as?   Try putting an actual value in your XML for `analysis=""`.

Comment: I haven't put a value in the sample I have uploaded but I do have a value here already.

Comment: @Kelv I have edited my answer, could you have a look? If that does not help, perhaps we have to wait for someone who is more proficient in Java.

Comment: @Kelv I have now tested the code, and my suggestion works - for exactly the document you have shown here, after correcting the input.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting the same when I try this on the document here but it is still not working on the full document I have saved - There's quite a few more elements that comes after that I haven't posted because I didn't think they mattered e.g. there is multiple collections all containing analysis attributes.

Comment: @Kelv If there are multiple `analysis` attributes, the code currently outputs the _first_ of them. If you'd like anyone to help find the problem, you really need to show the _actual_ document, or find out in what way it is different from what you have shown.